# What about this code breaks PHP4?

Tags: php

This code is part of a wordpress plugin. THe page breaks somewhere in the 2nd function and halts output of the page at that point.

I've determined the problem is PHP4 in all likelyhood. So I'm guessing its DOMDocument call if that's not supported by PHP4.

If so, how can I test for compatibility and gracefully exit without try/catch and without freezing the page?

```
function rseo_get_seo($check, $post){
    switch ($check)
    {
    case "h1": return rseo_doTheParse('h1', $post);
    case "h2": return rseo_doTheParse('h2', $post);
    case "h3": return rseo_doTheParse('h3', $post);
    case "img-alt": return rseo_doTheParse('img-alt', $post);
    }
}

function rseo_doTheParse($heading, $post){
//code breaks somewhere in here and freezes output of page. How can I error check this without try/catch?
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if($content=="") return false;
    $keyword = trim(strtolower(rseo_getKeyword($post)));
    @$dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML(strtolower($post->post_content));
    $xPath = new DOMXPath(@$dom);
    switch ($heading)
        {
        case "img-alt": return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(//img[contains(@alt, "'.$keyword.'")])');
        default: return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(/html/body//'.$heading.'[contains(.,"'.$keyword.'")])');
        }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `@` in front of the function calls and activate error reporting to see errors.

Comment: Wait a minute, I thought `case` always needed a `break`, otherwise it'll just execute all the cases below the proper `case`.

Comment: Does your host provide an option to switch from PHP 4 to PHP 5?

Comment: The question you’re asking in the body isn’t what the title of your question is, is it?

Comment: @Ben: The `return` will break the switch automatically because it ends the function. So there's no need for a `break` statement (it'd be unreachable for that case).

Comment: @Ben, @BoltClock Since there are only two cases, it would probably improve readability to instead use an if-else construct.

Comment: aside from using class_exists(), if the plug in is small, instead of exiting gracefully, maybe you could write alternative code using DOM XML (PHP 4 compatable).

Comment: I'm with @BoltClock on this one. Get rid of PHP4 if you can. With support for PHP 5.2 having ended in Dec 2010, still using PHP4 is Necrophilia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its version 4.4.9, which apparently contains the DOMDocument class, so that was not a reliable test. It may not fully support DOMDocument, but it passes the if(class_exists('DOMDocument')) test nonetheless.

```
if(class_exists('DOMDocument')) returns true!
```

The better test in this case, appears to be

```
If(PHP_VERSION < 5) {return false;} else {//proceed}
```

So, I'm still not certain what's breaking in PHP 4.4.9, perhaps its the loadXML() call.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on error_reporting() will help diagnose the cause of the problem.

To test if the DOM functions are available use following to wrap the affected code parts:

```
 if (class_exists("DOMDocument")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMDocument` class is only available to PHP5. You could test if the class is available to you by doing something like:

```
if(class_exists('DOMDocument')) {
  //DOMDocument exists, run DOM code (PHP5)
} else {
  //DOMDocument doesn't exists, do alternative code (PHP4)
}
```

Also, look DOM XML (PHP4) for ways you might write your alternative code. Here's a link to the manual: [PHP: DOM XML (PHP 4)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php)

Comment: I know for a fact this is PHP4, however, the code is still breaking at this point even with the check. If I just place a return false at top of that function, it proceeds without breaking

Comment: Its version 4.4.9, which apparently supports DOMDocument class, so that was not a reliable test. If(PHP_VERSION < 5) is much better. I still don't know why it breaks if 4.4.9 truly supports DOMDocument, but the class definitely is there.

Comment: @Scott B That is incorrect. Directly from the PHP manual: "The DOM extension allows you to operate on XML documents through the DOM API with PHP 5.

For PHP 4, use DOM XML." http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php

Comment: @Scott B If you're using PHP 4 and you *know* you're using PHP 4, why are you even doing a test to determine if it's PHP 4? Why not just rewrite the DOMDocument part using DOM XML and not worry about if DOMDocument is available to you?

Comment: The code is in a wordpress plugin in the wild. I have no way of knowing if the server its installed on has PHP4 unless I do a check and workaround. In this case, I was able to troubleshoot the client box and echo back the version. DOMDocument exists for PHP 4.4.9 according to my tests, so this is not a reliable test for PHP less than version 5.